# Pipe character in Golang

Tags: go, bit-manipulation

In the package `golang.org/x/sys/windows/svc` there is an example that contains this code:

```
const cmdsAccepted = svc.AcceptStop | svc.AcceptShutdown | svc.AcceptPauseAndContinue
```

What does the pipe `|` character mean?

Comment: [Bitwise OR](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Arithmetic_operators).

Answer (score 42, accepted):

As others have said, it's the bitwise [inclusive] OR operator. More specifically, the operators are being used to create bit mask flags, which is a way of combining option constants based on bitwise arithmetic. For example, if you have option constants that are powers of two, like so:

```
const (
    red = 1 << iota    // 1 (binary: 001) (2 to the power of 0)
    green              // 2 (binary: 010) (2 to the power of 1)
    blue               // 4 (binary: 100) (2 to the power of 2)
)
```

Then you can combine them with the bitwise OR operator like so:

```
const (
    yellow = red | green          // 3 (binary: 011) (1 + 2)
    purple = red | blue           // 5 (binary: 101) (1 + 4)
    white = red | green | blue    // 7 (binary: 111) (1 + 2 + 4)
)
```

So it simply provides a way for you to combine option constants based on bitwise arithmetic, relying on the way that powers of two are represented in the binary number system; notice how the binary bits are combined when using the OR operator. (For more information, see [this example](http://www.dylanleigh.net/notes/c-cpp-tricks.html#Using_"Bitflags") in the C programming language.) So by combining the options in your example, you are simply allowing the service to accept stop, shutdown *and* pause and continue commands.

Answer (score 4):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Arithmetic operators](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Arithmetic_operators)
>
> ```
> |    bitwise OR             integers
> ```

The Go programming language is defined in [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec).

Answer (score 1):

The `|` is not pipe character here,but **or** character,one of bit manipuations.

For example,`1 | 1 = 1`,`1 | 2 = 3`,`0 | 0 = 0`.

Comment: @bereal,yes,I'm sorry for my slip of the pen.